# Right clicking on the flash image, the first option takes the user to another website

Tags: php, flash, wordpress

Am working in a wordpress project. It uses many fash images. When right clicking on the flash image, the first option takes the user to another website. How can i remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would have been set up as a parameter of the swf by the Flash dev.

If you don't have access to the .fla source files you can try setting the menu parameter within your swf embed code to false.

Have a look here: http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/127/tn_12701.html